# Обработчик события на mousemove/анимация

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, css-animation

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать правильно функцию которая будет следить за положением курсора на экране и смещать блоки (через transform: translateX translateY), но на ограниченное пространство для каждого блока? Вот пример

```js
var bl1 = $(".block1"),
  bl2 = $(".block2"),
  bl3 = $(".block3"),
  bl4 = $(".block4");

var doc = {
  w: $(window).width(),
  h: $(window).height(),
  wC: $(window).width() / 2,
  hC: $(window).height() / 2
};
var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

$(window).resize(function() {
  doc = {
    w: $(window).width(),
    h: $(window).height(),
    wC: $(window).width() / 2,
    hC: $(window).height() / 2
  }
});

$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
  mouse.x = ((e.pageX - doc.w + doc.wC) / (doc.wC / 50));
  mouse.y = ((e.pageY - doc.h + doc.hC) / (doc.hC / 50));

  bl1.css('transform', 'translate(' + mouse.x + 'px, ' + mouse.y + 'px)');

});
```

```css
.wrappen {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: gold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.block3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.block4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappen">
  <div class="block1"> </div>
  <div class="block2"> </div>
  <div class="block3"> </div>
  <div class="block4"></div>  
</div>
```

но он немного не коректен, мне необходимо что б первый блок мог смещаться в приделах по Х ( -14 до 14) и по Y ( от -13 до 12), как бы следя за курсором, ну и с остальными блоками аналогично, только что б реакция отклика была скажем по +40мс (с небольшой задержкой) на каждый новый блок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть простой способ решить такую задержку, называется Slow Parent.

Для простоты я записал текущее отклонение в  `bl.data('x')` и  `bl.data('y')`.
Тогда координата будет рассчитываться как среднее арифметическое между текущим положением и положением рассчитанным от положения мыши:

```
 bl.data('x', (mouse.x + 1*bl.data('x')*(i-1))/i);
```

Где `i` номер блока. Итого функция которая будет рисовать кадр анимации:

```
function draw() {

  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

    bl=$(".block"+i)
    bl.data('x', (mouse.x + 1*bl.data('x')*(i-1))/i);
    bl.data('y', (mouse.y + 1*bl.data('y')*(i-1))/i);

    bl.css('transform', 'translate(' + bl.data('x') + 'px, '
                                     + bl.data('y') + 'px)');

  }
}
```

Остальное - дело техники. Создаем кроссплатформенный `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = function() {
  return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
  );
}();
```

И делаем на основе него функцию анимации:

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
  draw();
}
```

Ограничить координаты можно таким образом:

```
   mouse.x=Math.min(20,Math.max(-20,mouse.x))
   mouse.y=Math.min(20,Math.max(-20,mouse.y))
```

**Рабочий код:**

```js
var bl1 = $(".block1"),
  bl2 = $(".block2"),
  bl3 = $(".block3"),
  bl4 = $(".block4");

var doc = {
  w: $(window).width(),
  h: $(window).height(),
  wC: $(window).width() / 2,
  hC: $(window).height() / 2
};
var mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};


$(window).resize(function() {
  doc = {
    w: $(window).width(),
    h: $(window).height(),
    wC: $(window).width() / 2,
    hC: $(window).height() / 2
  }
});


window.requestAnimFrame = function() {
  return (
    window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
  );
}();

function animate() {
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
  draw();
}

  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
     $(".block"+i).data('x',0);
     $(".block"+i).data('y',0);
      
  }

function draw() {
 
  for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    bl=$(".block"+i)
    bl.data('x', (mouse.x + 1*bl.data('x')*(i-1))/i);
    bl.data('y', (mouse.y + 1*bl.data('y')*(i-1))/i);
  
    bl.css('transform', 'translate(' + bl.data('x') + 'px, '
                                     + bl.data('y') + 'px)');

  }
}



animate();

$(window).mousemove(function(e) {

  mouse.x = ((e.pageX - doc.w + doc.wC) / (doc.wC / 50));
  mouse.y = ((e.pageY - doc.h + doc.hC) / (doc.hC / 50));

   mouse.x=Math.min(20,Math.max(-20,mouse.x))
   mouse.y=Math.min(20,Math.max(-20,mouse.y))
   
});
```

```css
.wrappen {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: gold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.block3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.block4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrappen">
  <div class="block1"> </div>
  <div class="block2"> </div>
  <div class="block3"> </div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за метод. Но уже реализовал. проще http://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/ybeaxR

Comment: Можете оформить как ответ